# Answer should have been changed to wiki

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When the question for my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/2109/must-have-games/2123#2123) was changed to CW, I think my answer should have been made CW as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's not retro-active. I'm not sure it should be. If you provide an answer that was thoughtful, constructive, and helpful to many other people, you should be allowed to accept up-votes and in turn receive reputation. This should all happen regardless what the OP does with his question.

Comment: Yeah, it's up to the poster. The only time that I know of that forces a non-wiki answer to a wiki answer is when the post accumulates 30+ answers.

Comment: I see, okay.  I thought it was one CW all CW by rule. :)

Comment: @JP It is if the question is CW'd before any answers.

Answer (score 2):

Existing answers aren't changed to CW when the question is. It's up to the OPs to change them - though I think the moderators can go in and change them manually too.

Comment: If a Moderator goes in and forces a question to CW, it auto-forces all the answers as well. I think you can actually do a forced-cw on a question that is already CW and it will still auto-force the remaining answers that aren't cw to switch as well (haven't tried)

Comment: I was thinking of the mods changing the old answers - but thanks for the info

Comment: That's not the case anymore. Existing answers are now made CW when the question is. However, this wasn't retroactively added to older posts, so you may see old CW questions with non-CW answers.

Answer (score 1):

As other noted, the only "wiki-hammer" occurs when a question reaches 30 answers and is not already community wiki. At that point the Q and all As are forced into wiki.

Thus, any poster can opt in to wiki at the time of post, without affecting any other questions or answers.

(it is not possible to opt out of wiki, ever, though.)